# Facebook Graph API Comments not returning

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get the comments on ratings from the Facebook API.

First I request a list of ratings for a page I own:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/ratings?fields=open_graph_story?access_token=[access_token]
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "open_graph_story": {
        "message": "The best place in the world(s), and this is to reach that limit in the facebook review.",
        "start_time": "2018-05-24T22:56:23+0000",
        "type": "pages.rates",
        "data": {
          "rating": {
            "value": 5,
            "scale": 5
          },
          "review_text": "The best place in the world(s), and this is to reach that limit in the facebook review.",
          "is_hidden": false,
          "language": "en"
        },
        "id": "1805660589743235"
      }
    },
    {
      "open_graph_story": {
        "message": "Very good, not excellent though. Does Facebook change the created time if I edit this?",
        "start_time": "2018-04-12T20:25:26+0000",
        "type": "pages.rates",
        "data": {
          "rating": {
            "value": 3,
            "scale": 5
          },
          "review_text": "Very good, not excellent though. Does Facebook change the created time if I edit this?",
          "is_hidden": false,
          "language": "en"
        },
        "id": "106674383523012"
      }
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTAwMDA4OTc5MzQ4Mjc3Ojc3MzQwNTI3NjIwMTQyNAZDZD",
      "after": "MTAwMDI1NDEzNTE3NzgxOjc3MzQwNTI3NjIwMTQyNAZDZD"
    }
  }
}
```

(I removed some superfluous fields)

Then I use the id from the open_graph_story to get the comments for a rating:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/106674383523012/comments?access_token=[access_token]
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVFF5T1RNeU1UUTVPRGszTWpNMU9qRTFNalkwT0RZAeE1qZAz0ZD",
      "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZAFhKemIzSTZANVFE0TlRBM09URXlOamN5T1RreU9qRTFNamN5TURJek56ST0ZD"
    }
  }
}
```

It returns no data even though I can see comments on the actual rating when I visit the Facebook page. Why are no comments returned?

(Just to make sure that I had the correct permissions, I selected all the permissions possible in the graph api explorer.)

Comment: Maybe they broke it with the new privacy drive? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/ That mentions reviews and a change that takes effect since the 24th of May 2018

Comment: Let me know if you figure it out. I am also facing the exact same issue

Comment: I went to report a bug to Facebook and it looks like they already know about it: [see bug here](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/578924252491637/)

Comment: Update: Facebook reports that they have fixed the bug!